# Should I worry of memory leaks using server sent events?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, server-sent-events

Recently I found this technology: [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)
and I would like to use it with my backend code in **node.js**

I wanted to know, if It can cause a memory leaks?

Perhaps if it can open multiple connections to the same user?

Or if `.close()` wasn't called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server sent events in Node definitely do not cause memory leaks.

If you want to see an example of how to implement them I have written a two part blog post about exactly that.

1. [Part 1](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events-pt-1/)
2. [Part 2](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-apps-with-server-sent-events-pt-2/)

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the 2-part blog post. One thing I am struggling to understand is the event listeners are created **in** the url handler.
It ends up creating one too many and "MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected"
I am noticing that execution enters this url handler periodically(even without any new clients opening this url) which I am not sure how to avoid except for the first time